# Space after subsection

Tags: bibtex, sectioning, thesis, vertical-spacing, dvipdf

In some part of my thesis, there appears in a space after subsection while it seems fine in the rest subsections. While hit-and-trying for reducing the space after that particular subsection, I remove few words of text in that subsection. After compiling the code, the space is reduced. Why spacing is different in different part of thesis? What should I do to remove this without deleting any of the text.
I have defined the sections spacing as follows:

```
\titlespacing\section{-5pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{-5pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{-5pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
```

Images are added for reference.

---

[image: Subsection with spacing: Image1]

---

[image]

Comment: Try with `\raggedbottom` in the preamble (the default directive in standard classes  is `\flushbottom`).

Comment: Thanku so much!! Works perfect.

Comment: To answer your question, some spaces expand to fit the page and some don't, or at least not as much.  Look up "glue" in the TeXbook.  OTOH, \raggetbottom doesn't save you any space, it just moves it to the bottom of the page.